# Merging multiple jquery functions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I'm very new to jquery. I can seem to get stuff to work but the code is hideous in terms of length and I find myself repeating...

Can anyone assist with the shortest way to write the following... I've tried various things with it but it messes up the way in which the code works... this is basically a series of panels and buttons in a step by step process... when one button is clicked the next fades in and auto scrolls to a specific height.

```
<script>

        $(".steptwobtn").on( "click", function(e){
            $(".steptwo").fadeIn().css("display","block");
            $(".costs").fadeIn().css("display","block");

            var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-155
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        $(".stepthreebtn").on( "click", function(e){
            $(".stepthree").fadeIn().css("display","block");
            $(".size-costs span").css("visibility","visible");

            var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-155
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        $(".stepfourbtn").on( "click", function(e){
            $(".stepfour").fadeIn().css("display","block");
            $(".worktop-costs span").css("visibility","visible");

            var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-155
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        $(".stepfivebtn").on( "click", function(e){
            $(".stepfive").fadeIn().css("display","block");
            $(".appliances-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
            $(".install-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
            $(".total-costs span").css("visibility","visible");

            var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-155
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

I'm thinking there must be a neater way of writing this and not having to repeat the scroll function each time?

Many thanks in advance. I'm tearing my hair out!

G

Answer (score 0):

You can move the scroll logic out to a separate function and then call it from within each jQuery click handler:

```
<script>

    $(".steptwobtn").on( "click", function(e){
        $(".steptwo").fadeIn().css("display","block");
        $(".costs").fadeIn().css("display","block");

        scroll(this);
    });

    $(".stepthreebtn").on( "click", function(e){
        $(".stepthree").fadeIn().css("display","block");
        $(".size-costs span").css("visibility","visible");

        scroll(this);
    });

    $(".stepfourbtn").on( "click", function(e){
        $(".stepfour").fadeIn().css("display","block");
        $(".worktop-costs span").css("visibility","visible");

        scroll(this);
    });

    $(".stepfivebtn").on( "click", function(e){
        $(".stepfive").fadeIn().css("display","block");
        $(".appliances-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
        $(".install-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
        $(".total-costs span").css("visibility","visible");

        scroll(this);
    });

    function scroll(btn) {
        var target = $( $(btn).attr('href') );

        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-155
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Or, if you'd like to merge it all together you could do the following. The problem is that each function is doing something subtly different. For the following to work, you'd need to add an attribute to each btn, 'data-step-number', and change the css class of each button just to be 'stepbtn':

```
<script>

    $(".stepbtn").click(function(e) {

        var step = $(this).attr('data-step-number');

        $(".step" + step).fadeIn().css("display","block");

        switch (step) {

            case 2:
                $(".costs").fadeIn().css("display","block");
                break;

            case 3:
                $(".size-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
                break;

            case 4:
                $(".worktop-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
                break;

            case 5:
                $(".appliances-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
                $(".install-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
                $(".total-costs span").css("visibility","visible");
                break;
        }

        var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-155
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Ah thank you - thats got to be better... is there anyway of shortening the rest of it or do they have to rely on separate functions? Wasn't sure if there was a way of doing this?

Comment: I've added an additional example to the comment.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this - really helpful. Yeah that's an interesting way of doing it and makes sense. I've not come across 'case' yet but may look into this option. Thanks for your assistance!